# How to passa a Tensor Flow Distribution as parameter to another distribution?

Tags: tensorflow-probability

I am new in Tensor Flow Probability.
I am trying to create an  [Overdispersion Poisson Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdispersion), that have as rate parameter a continuous Gamma random variable.

How I should create this distribution?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a [negative binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma%E2%80%93Poisson_mixture), which is [available in TFP](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/NegativeBinomial). You may need to think carefully about parameterization here (there are a variety of conventions for Gamma parameterizations).

If you don't want the Gamma marginalized out, you can use TFP joint distributions, eg,

```py
jd = tfd.JointDistributionSequential([
   tfd.Gamma(concentration, rate),
   lambda rate: tfd.Poisson(rate)
])
```

For better numerics, you may want to use a log scale parameterization

```py
jd = tfd.JointDistributionSequential([
   tfd.ExpGamma(concentration, rate),
   lambda log_rate: tfd.Poisson(log_rate=log_rate)
])
```